# Finding the relative path

Tags: c++, c, path

Okay so I am using a method `_getcwd(cwd, _MAX_PATH)` that returns the full path of the current directory.

I am trying to set a `char *dir` variable to hold just `folder3` (the current folder name I am in) not the entire path.

So for clarity, I want `dir` to hold:

```
folder3
```

But instead `dir` holds:

```
c:\documents\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

How do I get rid of all the sections leading up the actual folder I am in? I have been working on it for hours and cannot find any help via the internet.

Comment: You might like to have look at `man strrchr` and `man strcpy`.

Comment: ... or as on windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftw0heb9.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
// string path
int pos = path.rfind('\\');
string relativePath = pos.substr(pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main( void )
{
   char buffer[_MAX_PATH];
   std::string bb,relative_path;
   if( _getcwd( buffer, _MAX_PATH ) == NULL )
      std::cout<< "Error !!" <<std::endl;
   else
   {
      bb=buffer;
      relative_path=bb.substr(bb.rfind("\\")+1);
      std::cout<<relative_path<<std::endl;

    }
}
```